# Stack points one above the other

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

To prevent over-plotting, I would like an alternative to jitter that simply stacks points one on top of the other around the mean (offsets them vertically by increments of given amount rather than add a random value as jitter does).

From this:

```
example <- data.frame(x=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2), y=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2))

qplot(data=example,x=x, y=y)
```

What I would like is something like this:

[image: example image]

This should probably be possible with `stat_bindot()`.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

None of the built in positions quite do this, and `geom_dotplot` isn't quite right either because it only works in one dimension. I've cobbled together a new position which does the right sort of thing, but requires manual tweaking to get everything right.

```
library("proto")
PositionNudge <- proto(ggplot2:::Position, {
  objname <- "nudge"
  adjust <- function(., data) {
    trans_x <- function(x) {
      lx <- length(x)
      if (lx > 1) {
        x + .$width*(seq_len(lx) - ((lx+1)/2))
      } else {
        x
      }
    }
    trans_y <- function(y) {
      ly <- length(y)
      if (ly > 1) {
        y + .$height*(seq_len(ly) - ((ly+1)/2))
      } else {
        y
      }
    }
    ddply(data, .(group), transform_position, trans_x=trans_x, trans_y=trans_y)
  }
})
position_nudge <- function(width = 0, height = 0) {
  PositionNudge$new(width = width, height = height)
}
```

I called it nudge, because the the other things I though of were already taken (stack, dodge)

To use it

```
ggplot(example, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point(aes(group=interaction(x,y)), size=5, 
             position=position_nudge(height=0.03))
```

[image]

You can also nudge in the horizontal direction

```
ggplot(example, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point(aes(group=interaction(x,y)), size=5, 
             position=position_nudge(width=0.03))
```

[image]

You have to specify the group interaction as an aesthetic to the `geom_point` and the exact width/height needed to be passed to the `position_nudge` depend on the size of the points and the size of the output. For example, with a 4x6 output, you need

```
ggplot(example, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point(aes(group=interaction(x,y)), size=10, 
                 position=position_nudge(height=0.13))
```

[image]

The value of 0.13 was just trial and error until it looked right. Some of the code and things learned from `geom_dotplot` could probably be re-used here to make this more robust. Also, I've not tested this with any data other than the `example` given, so it may break it some interesting ways. But it is, if nothing else, a start.

Comment: Planned to do something similar, but got stuck at the point where data had to be grouped by both `x` and `y` simultaneously. You solved this by the requirement of a `group` attribute. Any idea how to do without, i.e., automatically grouping by `interaction(x,y)`?

Comment: @krlmlr I think that if you replace `.(group)` with `.(x, y, group)` in the `ddply` call in the `adjust` function, then you may not need the explicit `group` in `aes`. Tried it and it seemed to work, but even less tested than what is here.

Answer (score 5):

Far from the sophistication of @Brian Diggs' nice answer, but a quick alternative where I use the 'dodge data' in the object created by `geom_dotplot` to generate new y values. Some manual tweeking is needed to get the scaling of 'dodge' right.

```
# create ggplot object with geom_dotplot
g1 <- ggplot(example, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_dotplot(stackdir = "center")

# grab dodge values from plot object
dodge <- ggplot_build(g1)[["data"]][[1]]$stackpos

# create new y values that are adjusted by 'dodge'
example$y2 <- example$y + dodge * 0.05

# plot using new y values
ggplot(example, aes(x = x, y = y2)) +
  geom_point(size = 5)
```

[image]

```
# seems to work decently on grouped data as well
df2 <- rbind(example, example)
df2$grp <- rep(c("a", "b"), each = 7)
df2

g2 <- ggplot(df2, aes(x = x, y = y, colour = grp)) +
  geom_dotplot(stackdir = "center", stackgroups = FALSE)

dodge <- ggplot_build(g2)[["data"]][[1]]$stackpos

df2$y2 <- df2$y + dodge * 0.04

ggplot(df2, aes(x = x, y = y2, colour = grp)) +
  geom_point(size = 5, position = position_dodge(width = 0.05))
```

[image]